# tcp_reordering setting for tcp connection

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel

From my understanding, the tcp connection's reordering value should scaled between /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_reordering (default 3)and /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_reordering(default 300). But when I change the tcp_reordering from default value `3` to `6`, the new connection still has the reordering value to 3 instead of 6 or more. I setup about 20K new connections, the result from the `ss -i` shows there are few connection with the tcp_reordering to 6 or more, most are still has the value equals to `3`.  The tcp server is running inside a container, and I also changed the proc value inside container.

Our kernel version is:

```
-bash-4.2# uname -r
4.15.0-43.generic.x86_64
```

Comment: So you are saying that `ss -i` is actually reporting a value of three?  As far as I know, it should only show a value when it is [not 3](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/misc/ss.c#n2584).

Comment: As best I can tell, tcp_reordering was "[namespace-ified](https://lwn.net/Articles/674510/)" in your kernel version, so I believe you are correct that you should set it in the namespace/container. I would be concerned that whatever container you are using is preventing you from setting the sysctl. Did you check to make sure the attempt to change it actually changed the setting?

Comment: It doesn't print out the reordering value,  because it equals 3.

Comment: The container has NET_ADMIN capability, so it can change the kernel parameter.

Comment: I understand you think it can, but because your observation is that is doesn't seem to change, did you check that /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_reordering was actually changed in the container?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the sysctl is enabled for network namespaces in 4.15.0 because it appears in `ipv4_net_table` in [`sysctl_net_ipv4.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/net/ipv4/sysctl_net_ipv4.c#L816).  You can verify this by creating a test network namespace with `sudo ip netns add testns` then `sudo ip netns exec testns ls /proc/sys/net/ipv4`.  If it appears in the list, you can test if you can set it with, e.g., `sudo ip netns exec testns bash`.  If it appears and you can set it, then I would see if you need to white list the sysctl in your container system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think I found the reason. The new created socket will inherit this value from listening socket.  If the server start to listen the port before tcp_reordering change, then the afterward socket's reordering value will have the same value  with the listening socket, instead from ` /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_reordering`

Comment: I believe you are correct.  The reordering value is a per socket estimate of the reordering on the wire which in the case of the listening socket is initialized to the sysctl.  When a connection is accepted, the child socket is copied with `sock_copy` from the listening socket, thereby inheriting the reordering from the parent.